# php removing duplicate html body and header

Tags: php, tags, strip-tags

I have a string that it is echoed into the current document, however, I would like to insert only the content inside the `<body>`, how can I strip those tags so I end up with a valid document.

```
$string = '
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- leave any tag within the body -->
    </body>
    </html>
';

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo $string; // new valid content  ?>
    <!-- more content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where do you get that string?

Answer (score 0):

You could search for the `<body>` tag  and add 6 to find the start point and then search for the `</body>` to find the end point and then do a substr on the string. You need to make sure that the  tag does not have any attributes in it. If you want to really make sure that this is properly done, find `<body` and then find the next `>` and add 1 for the start point.

Comment: Or you could just use a regex if you're lazy. ;)

Answer (score 0):

From php.net;

```
<?php
function strip_selected_tags($str, $tags = array(), $stripContent = false)
{
    preg_match_all("/<([^>]+)>/i", $tags, $allTags, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    foreach ($allTags[1] as $tag) {
        $replace = "%(<$tag.*?>)(.*?)(<\/$tag.*?>)%is";
        $replace2 = "%(<$tag.*?>)%is";
        echo $replace;
        if ($stripContent) {
            $str = preg_replace($replace,'',$str);
            $str = preg_replace($replace2,'',$str);
        }
            $str = preg_replace($replace,'${2}',$str);
            $str = preg_replace($replace2,'${2}',$str);
    }
    return $str;
}
?>
```